# Solving an Inhomogeneous Wave Equation with free end boundary conditions.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Solve
> $$\begin{aligned}
> \text{D.E.}&  & &u_{tt} = 4u_{xx}~, \quad 0 \leq x \leq \pi~, ~-\infty < t < \infty \\
> \text{B.C.}& & &u_x(0,t) =-1~, \quad u_x(\pi, t) =1 \\
> \text{I.C.}& & &u(x,0) = \frac{x^2}{\pi}-x+2\cos(3x)~, \quad u_t(x,0)=cos(x)
> \end{aligned}$$

#### My attempt:

The problem is in the form of

$$\begin{aligned}
\text{D.E.}& & & u_{tt}=a^2u_{xx}~, \quad  0 \leq x \leq L~, ~-\infty <t< \infty\\
\text{B.C.}& & & u_x(0,t) =c~, \quad  u_x(L, t) =d \\
\text{I.C.}& & & u(x,0) = f(x)~, \quad  u_t(x,0)=g(x) 
\end{aligned}$$
where
$$u_p(x,t) = \frac{a^2(d-c)}{2L}t^2+\frac{d-c}{2L}x^2+cx$$

Since $a = 2,~d= 1,~c = -1,~$ and $L = \pi$,

$$\begin{aligned}
u_p(x,t) &= \frac{2^2(1-(-1))}{2\pi}t^2+\frac{1-(-1)}{2\pi}x^2-1x \\
&= \frac{4(1+1))}{2\pi}t^2+\frac{1+1}{2\pi}x^2-1x \\
&= \frac{4(2))}{2\pi}t^2+\frac{2}{2\pi}x^2-1x \\
&= \frac{4}{\pi}t^2+\frac{1}{\pi}x^2-x
\end{aligned}$$

The solution , if it exists, is then $u(x,t) =u_p(x,t)+v(x,t)$ where $v(x,t)$ solves the following familiar related homogeneous question
$$\begin{aligned}
\text{D.E.} &&&  v_{tt}=a^2v_{xx}~, \quad   0 \leq x \leq L~,~ -\infty <t< \infty \\
 \text{B.C.} &&& v_x(0,t) = c ~,~ v_x(L, t) =d \\
 \text{I.C.} &&& v(x,0) = f(x)-u_p(x,0)~, \quad   v_t(x,0)=g(x)-(u_p)_t(x,0)
 \end{aligned}$$

So, my I.C. for $v(x,0)$ would be $$\frac{x^2}{\pi}-x + 2\cos(3x)-(\frac{1}{\pi}x^2-x)$$

All of the terms would cancel out except $2cos(3x)$. Similarly for $v_t(x,0)$ I have

$$\cos(x)-\frac{4}{\pi}t^2 \qquad \text{and} \qquad \cos(x) -\frac{8t}{\pi}$$

#### The answer to this problem is given as

$$\frac{4t^2}{\pi} + \frac{x^2}{\pi} - x + 2 \cos(6t) \cos(3x)+\frac{1}{2} \sin(2t) \cos(2x)$$

I know that I got the first part right, but where did the $2\cos(6t)$ and $\sin(2t)$ come from? Does it have something to do with harmonics?